# web2py: Check if record in database?

Tags: database, web2py

example table:

```
db.define_table('pet',
    Field('name'),
    Field('owner_id','reference person'),
    Field('location_id','reference location'))
```

1) How can I check if there's a pet, called `"Furry"`, owned by person `15` in location `26`?

2) How can I check if there are any pets of person `8` in location `76`? If so, return them.

Comment: Have you read the documentation (e.g., [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Logical-operators) and [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#count--isempty--delete--update))? Why don't you give it a try and report back with your failed code if you have problems?

Comment: Yes I have. I just thought there was a straight function for that purpose and I couldn't find. Reading those paragraphs again, it seems there are quite a few indirect ways for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

```
db((db.pet.name == 'Furry') & (db.pet.owner_id == 15) & (db.pet.location_id == 26)).count()
```

**Question 2**

```
db((db.pet.owner_id == 8) & (db.pet.location_id == 76)).count()

# if you have the name of the owner and the location you can even do 

db((db.pet.owner_id == 
    db(db.person.name == 'NO_8_PERSON_NAME'
       ).select(db.persone.id).first().id) & 
   (db.pet.location_id == 
    db(db.location.location_name == 'NO_76_LOCATION_NAME'
       ).select(db.location.id).first().id)).count()
```